Convert a sequence of exr files to mp4 using moviepy
I have a sequence of exr files which I want to convert into a video using moviepy. When Since the colors in the exrs need be converted (otherwise the video appears almost black) I need to specify a color transfer characteristic. When I run ffmpeg directly using

ffmpeg -y -apply_trc iec61966_2_1 -i input_%d.exr -vcodec mpeg4 output.mp4

everything is working perfectly fine. However, if I read the exrs using clip = ImageSequenceClip("folder_to_my_exrs/", fps = 24) and try to write the video using .write_videofile("output.mp4", codec = "mpeg4", ffmpeg_params = ["-apply_trc", "iec61966_2_1"]) I'm receiving the error

b'Codec AVOption apply_trc (color transfer characteristics to apply to EXR linear input) specified for output file #0 (output.mp4) is not an encoding option.\r\n'

I don't really understand this. What can I do?

That's because apply_trc is an input option (given before -i in ffmpeg command) while ffmpeg_params presumably is specifying only the output option based on the function name write_videofile

@kesh I see. But is there any way how I achieve the same output as with the direct ffmpeg call?

if it is input option then maybe it could be used in ImageSequenceClip(). You can even check source code to see if it can get extra parameters. or if you can change it - or ask author for changes.

do you have to do it with MoviePy? Maybe ffmpeg-python could be better for this. OR maybe you should use subprocess.run() to execute ffmpeg with your parameters.

@0xbadf00d - what @furas says. If you're just transcoding, I'd use subprocess.run.
